# How to check touch proximity to an UIImageView?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, sensors, uitouch, proximity

Does anyone know how I would check the touch proximity to an UIImageView in Xcode? I am trying to check if the touch is within 25 pixels of an UIImageView which moves around the screen. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you get the touch with:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

Next, you want to be checking for the locationInView relative to your image view.

```
CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInView:self]; // or possibly myimage instead of self.
```

Next, CGRectContainsPoint returns a boolean.  It should be:

```
if ( CGRectContainsPoint( imgView.frame, touchlocation ) ) {
   // inside imgView
} else {
   // outside imgView Now we will found out is it within proximityImgViewRect
   CGRect *proximityImgViewRect = CGRectMake( imgView.frame.origin.x-25,imgView.frame.origin.y - 25, imgView.frame.size.width+50,imgView.frame.size.height+50); 
   if ( CGRectContainsPoint( proximityImgViewRect.frame, touchlocation ) ) {
     // inside proximityImgViewRect
   } else {
    //outside proximityImgViewRect
   }
}
```